# React Router: history.push("") and <Link to= ""> not working properly together

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am facing a small problem related to react router.
So I have two components. Let's say A and B.
A has a button(let's say x) which is redirecting to B(`<Link to="/B">`).
Now from B, there are two ways to go back to A:

1. There is a back button(`<Link to="/A">`)
2. There is a navbar also which has a nav which redirects to A(This is done using `this.props.history.push("A")`).

Now coming to the problem, when I click on x and come back to A using the 1st way, and then click x again, it redirects me to B which is the expected behaviour.
But when I click on x and come back to A using the 2nd way, and then click x again, nothing happens. I am not getting redirected to B.

react router version: 5

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Should it be `history.push("/A")` or `history.push("/B")` with a valid absolute path? It's a bit unclear what may be happening here; we may need quite a bit more context. Can you update question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Are you using history package? If so, check if the version is compatible with react-router@5. History package should be in version 4. Look into [history docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) and the 'Documentation' section.

Comment: not explicitly..just using react-router-dom, it is installing history as a peer dependency. It is installing history v4. The problem is not related to that. this.props.history.push() is working fine